# How to download .docx document to the phone from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

Currently using Google Drive version 2.18.252.01.45 and I have a .docx document in my drive that doesn't download to the phone as a .docx document. It downloads as a .pdf document. I tried looking for options similar to those found in a web browser which allows you to '**Download as**', but the Android app doesn't have that option. It automatically converts the .docx document to PDF and then downloads it.

Any way to download a document to Android from Google Drive in its original format?

Comment: I may have a slightly an older vesion than yours (`2.17.372.10.45`) but I am pretty sure it downloads the `.docx` file without converting to "pdf) as you mention. Do you have a word reader installed on you device? other than that Iam not sure why that is happening

Comment: Drive on Android doesn't permit that as you discovered. You would need to use a third party office app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.wps.moffice_eng)

Answer (score 1):

You can download `docx` documents as stated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzZzD.png):

> Which file formats can I download?
>
> You can download files in these formats:
>
> - Documents: HTML, RTF, DOCX, OpenOffice, PDF, EPUB, Text.
> - Spreadsheets: CSV, HTML, ODS, PDF, XLSX, TXT (only for a single sheet).
> - Presentations: PDF, PPTX, TXT.
> - Drawings: PNG, JPEG, SVG, PDF.

Using version `2.19.013.08.35` of Google Drive, it does not convert `docx` documents to `pdf`.

1. Open Google Drive, go to the folder your file is located.
2. Click on the 3-dot, then click `Download`.

[image: IMG:]

If you are still unable to download documents as `docx`, verify that you have not by mistake converted it to `pdf`,